# SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, installation

I had SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition installed on a server. Due to some drive reconfiguration, I had to do a reinstallation. I uninstalled using the program and features and just as I was about to launch the setup to install it again, I went ahead and deleted the "Microsoft SQL Server" folder under "Program files".

Most of the files were deleted and few remained, mainly in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2016".

The problem is now when I am trying to launch the setup, it displays the error:

> TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
>
> Error code 0x84B10001.

Not sure how to proceed next.

Comment: The driver reconfiguration looks to be the root of your issue.  What did you "reconfigure" and why did it require a re-installation?

Comment: i delete all things from %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server
and solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but some suggestion:

Use SQL Server Installation Center to start: System Configuration Checker. This tool will check for conditions that prevent a successful SQL server installation.

[image: SQL Server Installer]

You can alterantivly:

1) Check setup log files at %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup Bootstrap\Log

2) Check Your .net 4.0 installation and search your GAC for redundant dll files: